# Audio recording using AVAudioEngine with setting output audio port

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

In order to make avaliable playback and recording at the same time we use these methods for setting `AVAudioSession` category:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:NULL];
```

By doing so, the output audio port switches from line out speaker to built-in speaker. In the loop recording window we need simultaneously working playback from line out speaker and audio recording from microphone. To play sound from line out speaker after setting `AVAudioSession` category we use a method for setting output audio port:

> [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
>   overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];

We try to arrange both recording and playback using AVAudio Engine.
 Structure of `AVAudioEngine` connections:

```
//     input->inputMixer->mainEqualizer ->tap
//         0  0                  |0
//                               |
//                               |  
//                               |0             0  0
//     recordPlayerNode→recordMixer→meteringMixer→|
//                   0  1         0  0            | 
//                                                |->mainMixer->out
//                                                |
//                                   volumePlayer→|
//                                             0  1
```

**After execution overrideOutputAudioPort the recording feature stops working on iPhone 6S and higher.** We perform recording in this manner:

```
if(self.isHeadsetPluggedIn)
{
  volumePlayer.volume = 1;
}
else
{
    volumePlayer.volume = 0.000001;
}

[volumePlayer play];



[mainEqualizer installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:0 format:tempAudioFile.processingFormat block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer *buf, AVAudioTime *when)
{
    if(self.isRecord)
    {

    [volumePlayer scheduleBuffer:buf completionHandler:nil];

    recordedFrameCount += buf.frameLength;


    if (self.isLimitedRecord && recordedFrameCount >= [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].sampleRate * 90)
    {
        self.isRecord = false;
        [self.delegate showAlert:RecTimeLimit];
    }
    NSError *error;

    [tempAudioFile writeFromBuffer:buf error:&error];

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Allert while write to file: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }

    [self updateMetersForMicro];
    }
    else
    {

        [mainEqualizer removeTapOnBus:0];
        [self.delegate recordDidFinish];
        callbackBlock(recordUrl);
        [mainEngine stop];
    }

}];
```

During the investigation we have discovered an interesing fact – if

volumePlayer.volume = 1;

when headphones are not connected, then the buffer that comes from microhone starts to fill and the sound keeps recording, but there appears an effect of a very loud sound repetition in the speaker. Otherwise, `PCMBuffer` is filled with zeros.

The question is: how can we set `AVAudioSession`, or recording process so we could record audio using a microphone and play audio using line out speaker?

P.S. Recording with `AVAudioRecorder` works correctly with these settings.